# How to split >1digit integers list and create a list from that digits? Python

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have list `a = [23, 2]`. I need to split every element in list and then combine them to one list.
 So result be like `a = [2, 3, 2]`
What I have for now is:

```
list = [int(i) for i in str(map([], map(lambda x: x*2, list(reversed(numlist))[1::2])))]
```

Where `map(lambda x: x*2, list(reversed(numlist))[1::2])))` is the list of even indexed numbers (2, 4, 6...) each multiplied by 2.

It gives me: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<'` on this line.

Comment: obviously you are passing an invalid list... please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> map(int, ''.join(map(str, a)))
[2, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two level List Comprehension:

```
a = [23, 2]
digits = [ int(x) for num in a for x in str(num) ]
```

Comment: `list(str(num))` is unnecessary. Just use `str(num)` you can iterate directly over strings...

Answer (score 1):

You can first change list to string then change this string back to integer list.
Here is an example.

```
a = [23, 2]
a = [int(j) for j in ''.join([str(i) for i in a])]
print(a)
```